# How in Vim to visual select lines from command mode?

Tags: command-line

In vim we can move, copy or delete lines from command line

Copy from 12 to 14 code and paste here:

```
:12,14t.
```

Move code from lines 14 - 16 to 20:

```
:14,16m20
```

But how to make visual selection from line 10 to 20 from command line?

And a relative question.

How to paste code from external buffer to the line 14, for example?

Comment: What do you mean by "external buffer"?

Comment: There's the `:{range}read [filename]` command to read from a file.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what's the use case for creating a visual selection from line numbers? For any operation, the line numbers suffice. Usually, visual mode is employed to (well) visually show the user what they select. I'm under the impression this question turns the concept of visual mode upside down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean from Vim command line I would do:

```
:normal 10GV20G
```

To past right after line 14 I would do:

```
:14put
```

Comment: `:14put` (or `:14pu`, even) would be more straightforward.